# Karate API - How to configure client cookie decoder to LAX (relax)?

Tags: netty, karate

One of our services is responding with an encryted cookie key name,  the key name has symbols that are not able to be parsed using the Netty's strict decoder.

How we can configure this test to skip the Strict decoding and process the cookie as is in Karate API version 1.1.0 or 1.0.1?

---

com.intuit.karate.http.Response.java:

```
while(var3.hasNext()) {
  String value = (String)var3.next();
  Cookie cookie = ClientCookieDecoder.STRICT.decode(value);  //<<<<---- value = cookie with symbols, returns null
  map.put(cookie.name(), Cookies.toMap(cookie));  //<<<---- null exeption
}
```

---

10:13:31,606 DEBUG karate.io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ClientCookieDecoder:74 - Skipping cookie because value 'tKBWtkk' contains invalid char ''
10:13:31,606 ERROR com.intuit.karate:122 -
When method post
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: it is possible this is a bug. can you follow these instructions to replicate, it will help everyone: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and if you can do some research if related to this ticket, even better: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1777

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, @Peter Thomas,  I try the * configure followRedirects = false that didn't work.  Tried to replicate in a simpler project, no luck.   Will give it another shoot,  any other suggestions?

Comment: nope :( a way to replicate is really important